# Counting lines, words, and characters

Tags: c

I am a new to programming. I am trying to write a program that reads lines, words and characters from a text file. Here is the code below.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input;

    int character, newword, newline, state;
    char c;
    state = OUT;
    character = newline = newword =0;
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if ( input == NULL){
        printf("Error! Can not read the input\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF){
        character++;
        if (c <'a' && c >'z'){;}
        if ( c <'A' && c >'Z'){;}

        if (c == '\n'){
            newline++;
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
            state = OUT;
        }

        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            newword++;
        }

    }

    printf("The number of lines: %d\n", newline);

    printf("The number of words: %d\n", newword);

    printf("The number of characters: %d\n", character);

    fclose(input);
}
```

I have been trying to figure how not to read special characters such as `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `_`, `+`.

I tried using if statements so it won't read the special characters but it reads it. I think one the if statement for the capital letters is wrong because it probably will not read lower case letters.

In the file the following text is in it,

```
!!.
```

and it outputs in terminal:

```
The number of lines: 2
The number of words: 5
The number of characters: 7
```

However, if I take out the two for loops `(c < 'A' && c > 'Z')` and `(c < 'a' && c > 'z')`, then the output becomes

```
The number of lines: 2
The number of words: 1
The number of characters: 7
```

Any hints to fix this problem (I do not want the Answer!)?

Comment: `c <'a' && c >'z'` always false.

Comment: Succinctly, you can't stop the program from reading punctuation if the file contains punctuation.  You have to deal with it.  You can decide how to count it.  Normally, words are separated from each other by white space (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc).  Anything that isn't white space is part of a 'word'.  You can refine your choices — you can ignore punctuation, for example.  You should look up the header `<ctype.h>` and functions (macros) such as `isalpha()` and `ispunct()` and `isspace()`.

Comment: You can also look up the source code for the GNU utility `wc` and see how it works.

Comment: You might note that the sequence `if (c <'a' && c >'z'){;} if ( c <'A' && c >'Z'){;} if (c == '\n'){` always runs the test against `'a'` and `'z'` and the test against `'A'` and `'Z'` (both of which are deeply flawed) and then runs the test against `'\n'`.  If you didn't want all three tests run, you should use `else if` for the second and third tests: `if (c <'a' && c >'z'){ … } else if ( c <'A' && c >'Z'){ …} else if (c == '\n') { … }` etc.

Comment: Also, you must use `int c;`, not `char c;`.  That's because `getchar()` returns an `int`, which is either a value between 0 and 255 (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` which is usual), or the extra value EOF (which is negative, usually but not necessarily `-1`).  Since an 8-bit `char` can't represent 257 values, one of two things happens: (1) if `char` is a signed type, a valid character (sometimes ÿ U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is treated the same as EOF, so the input stops early, or (2) if `char` is an unsigned type, the `!= EOF` condition is always true and the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: Two things of note.  One; by long standing convention, 0 is input, and 1 is output (stdin is file descriptor 0, stdout is file descriptor 1)  If you define IN as 1 and OUT as 0, you are just asking for trouble.  Two; use useful error messages.  `if( input == NULL) { perror(argv[1]);]`.

Comment: Don't forget to glance at the right column of the page labeled **Related** as there are multiple questions concerning this very problem that will have a wealth of *related* information...

Answer (score 1):

Your if must be something like:

```
if ('a' <= c && c <='z'){character++;}
else if ( 'A' <= c && c <='Z'){character++;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to increase your character counter when the character is between the interval 'a' and 'z' or the interval 'A' and 'Z', and then, since the escape sequence '\n' creates a new line, this also means that you are dealing with a new word, thus you should increment this counter too. And finally you can check for the space or the horizontal tab to increment the new word counter.

```
if ((c <'a' && c >'z') || ( c <'A' && c >'Z')){
   ++character;  
}
else if (c == '\n'){
   ++newline;
   ++newword;
}
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\t'){
   ++newword;
}
```